# How to choose between the many meanings of 'substantive'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese

I don't  duplicate the prior https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/32122/8712. There, I couldn't identify the unique correct definition. Here, I don't know how to choose  between three disparate [definitions](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/substantive), all of which can apply :

> the Constitutional Reform Act (CRA) 2005
>   provides, in s 1, that the Act does not adversely affect
>   ‘the existing constitutional principle
>   of the rule of law’ or
>   ‘the Lord Chancellor’s existing constitutional role in relation
>   to that principle’.
>   ...as Lord Bingham pointed out, the Act does not actually
>   defi ne what is meant by the rule of law, or indeed the Lord Chancellor’s role in relation
>   to it. He also recognised the difficulty in fixing a single meaning or in fact any **substantive**
>   content to the principle, citing various different academic references to it...
>
> Definition`1.` Having a firm basis in reality and so important
>   2. Having a separate and independent existence.
>   3. (Of law) defining rights and duties, as opposed to giving the procedural rules by which those rights and duties are enforced.

1. This is a significant Act so it's important. Is Definition 1 the answer?
2. Lord Bingham 'recognised the difficulty' of, separate definitions. Is 'separate' the meaning?
3. This is about law so this also applies, but is Definition 3 the answer?

Source: p 30, The English Legal System 2012-2013, Gary Slapper

Comment: @snailplane Thanks.  I tried to explain at the start why it's not a duplicate; does it help?

Comment: You should edit the other question to incorporate these definitions. I don't think this needs to be (nor should be) two separate questions.

Comment: @J.R. Thanks. Would you please advise on your last sentence? Please see http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/should-my-questions-substantive-be-bisected-or-merged.

Comment: I've already given my opinion; let's see what others say.